Finding matrix-valued square roots with real entries
Given a real-valued square matrix $A$ I want to find real-valued matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$, what algorithm should I use for this?
For instance, for
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
I see the following:
$$A^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$A^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$A^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 i & 0 \\
 0 & i \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$A^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -i & 0 \\
 0 & -i \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Meanwhile standard approach relying on eigenvalue decomposition give imaginary-valued matrix
$$A^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 i & 0 \\
 0 & i \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
I can recover these with some probability by using eigenvalue decomposition on a noise-perturbed version of $A$ but I'm wondering if there's a standard deterministic approach.
Edit, in this case the ambiguity of 180 degree rotations come from the fact that you can obtain it by combining clockwise rotations, counter-clockwise rotations, and 2 extra transformations, visualized below by plotting $(\operatorname{Re}(x),\operatorname{Re}(y),\operatorname{Im}(x))$ for $x=B^p x_0$ for $p\in(0,4)$
Notebook





As a matter of language, those are not "real-valued square roots" (and I don't even know what the real-valued square root of a matrix might be).  Those are matrix-valued square roots with real entries, or $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$-valued square roots.

"What matrix decomposition should I use" how nice your matrix really is? If the matrix is diagonalizable, then $A^{1/2}=PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$ where $P$ the model matrix and $D$ contains the eigenvalues diagonally.

@CroCo that approach fails for $A$ in the question, it gives matrix with purely imaginary components

What is your definition for "real-valued square root"? It seems to me your question needs more info as it appears you did modify the post.

@CroCo square root of $A$ is a matrix B such that $B^2$=A. Real-valued indicates this matrix is real valued

Come on guys! He clearly means: if $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$, matrices $B\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ such that $A=B^2$.

Edited the post with some animations I've made for myself to understand why there are 4 different square roots. Still curious how I go about extracting the real-valued root in practice

There are infinitely many square roots in $M_2(\Bbb R)$: $\pmatrix{a&b\-\frac{1+a^2}b&-a}$, where $b\ne0$.
